# How i can create two differet sites on apache 2.2 / windows server

Tags: hosts, apache2.2

In my case, all domains redirect to memberspage.com when I enter domain names in the browser.

In httpd.conf i use:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ServerName memberspage.com
    ServerAlias www.memberspage.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/memberspage.com/"
    <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/memberspage.com/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ServerName mysite2.com
    ServerAlias mysite2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mysite2.com/"
    <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mysite2.com/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       memberspage.com
127.0.0.1       mysite2.com
```

Comment: What about http://mysite2.com:81/ ?

Comment: When i entering mysite2.com browser loading memberspage.com files not mysite2.com

Comment: You put mysite2.com on port 81. Did you try specifying that port?

Comment: Yup but result same

Comment: What about `http://127.0.0.1:81/` ?

Comment: The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Ok, I can only guess what's in your htdocs/ - maybe `http://127.0.0.1:81/index.html` ?

Comment: oh, sorry mysite2.com folder was out from htdocs, now i put it in htdocs folder and http://127.0.0.1:81 is opeping correct site without error and redirect, but when i enter mysite2.com still opening memberspage.com, in htdocs i have 3 folder, phpmyadmin, memberspage.com and mysite2.com

Comment: I do not know if that Windows hosts trick will actually work in distinguishing your hosts. What does `ping mysite2.com` yield? Besides, you might want to use port 80 (or 443) only for accessing both domains. This can be done using [SNI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/namebasedsslvhostswithsni).